# container view under navigation bar didnt shift up when search bar selected

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I customly add UISearchBar controller in the navigationItem. And it works fine on iphone but giving issue on ipad.

I am using a container view under the navigation bar on which i am calling different view controllers. But as soon as i select the search bar the search bar goes up to hide the status bar but the container view under the navigation didn't shift up.

```
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    if let textfield = self.searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {     
        if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {
            backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
            backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
        }
    }
    self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.cityworksBlue()
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = false;
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true

        navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }
```

[image: image 1 before]
[image: image 2 after selecting search bar]

**What i want to do is if search bar shifts upwards then container view should also shift upward. It works in iphones but giving problem in ipad.**

Comment: What is that you want? To not hide navigation bar? You’re setting hidesNacigationBarDuringPresentation to true.

Comment: What i want to do is if search bar shifts upwards then container view should also shift upward. It works in iphones but giving problem in ipad.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution by selection "Under Top Bars" option.

[image: first select]
[image: Then check the "Under Top Bars" option]